# Why is the coefficient symbol changed?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, matrix

[image: Original problem text (German language) and schematic]

I'm solving this very basic problem with 3 voltage sources and I have no problem getting to the equations to create the matrix [U=RI],

These are:
I1-I2-I3 = 0

U1-I1R1-I2R2-U2 = 0

U2+i2R2-I3R3-U3 = 0

Values are:
U1 = 36 V
U2 = 24 V
U3 = 12 V
R1 = 20 Ω
R2 = 25 Ω
R3 = 30 Ω

and I understand that the coefficients are what comes into the matrix, but I don't understand why the result is the following:

```
1  -1  -1  I1 = 0

20  25  0  I2 = 12 V

0  -25  30 I3 = 12 V
```

Specifically in the second line that the result is 12 V [in my mind it should be 6 V]
And especially in the last line, that 25 is negative and the last equation was U2 +I2R2....!!!

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are really just three voltage source with different voltages and source resistances. Choosing the direction for \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$ they way they are in the problem is just dumb, so we flip them around (and flip them back when we are done). Then the whole thing becomes completely symmetric and we have

\$U_1- R_1I_1 = U_2- R_2I_2 = U_3 - R_3I_3\$

\$I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 0\$

The first equation we can rewrite as (for example)

\$R_1I_1 - R_2I_2 = U_1 - U_2\$

\$R_2I_2 - R_3I_3 = U_2 - U_3\$

And set up the matrix equation as

\$ \begin{bmatrix} R_1 & -R_2 &  0 \\ 0 &  R_2 &  -R_3\\ 1 & 1 &  1\\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} I_1 \\ I_2 \\ I_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} U_1-U_2 \\ U_2-U_3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \$

Unfortunately this doesn't invert nicely, but you get something like \$I_1 = 0.51892A\$ etc. The voltage over all sources is \$25.622V\$